# Syntax error while creating primary key

Tags: c#, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm creating VF tables using C#. The Create Table statement looks like

```
{CREATE TABLE NMMAIN (
   NAMETYPE Character(4),
   NAME_ID Numeric(11) AUTOINCREMENT,
   RACE Character(2),
   RELIGION Character(10),
   REPORTAREA Character(8),
   RESTRICTNM Numeric(1),
   RES_STATUS Character(1),
   SEX Character(1),
   SKINTONE Character(6),
   CONSTRAINT primKey PRIMARY KEY(NAME_ID)
  )}
```

This throws a "Syntax Error" on executing the query. It does work fine if I don't add the Constraint. any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would check for newline character and make sure it is preceded with semi-colon

Comment: You cannot use primary key in a free table (separate DBF file). If you want to, the table is being created should belong to a .DBC database.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the query to use the UNIQUE keyword instead of the PRIMARY KEY and now it works fine. But adding the AUTOINC key still throws a Syntax Error. Is there a different keyword to auto-increment?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax. Looking at the [`CREATE TABLE` syntax for Visual Foxpro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z1cc2za0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the correct syntax would be either:

```
CREATE TABLE NMMAIN (
   ...,
   NAME_ID Numeric(11) AUTOINC PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
)
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE NMMAIN (
   ...,
   NAME_ID Numeric(11) AUTOINC,
   ...,
   PRIMARY KEY NAME_ID TAG primKey
)
```

Note I have used `AUTOINC` instead of `AUTOINCREMENT`, as the reference I link to doesn't show `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: thank you for replying. I did try your suggestions but they both throw a "SQL: Statement is invalid." Do you see anything else wrong with the query?

Comment: The last time I used is Visual FoxPro is ages ago. I suggest you go over the create table syntax page and see if you notice anything. Other than that: maybe someone else will see this question and know something.

Answer (score 0):

Your final problem, I think, is that only the Integer type can use AUTOINC, not Numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CREATE TABLE clause definition:

```
CREATE TABLE | DBF Table_Name 
 [CODEPAGE = nCodePage]
 (FieldName1 FieldType [( nFieldWidth [, nPrecision] )] [NULL | NOT NULL] 
 [AUTOINC [NEXTVALUE NextValue [STEP StepValue]]] 
 [, FieldName2 ... ] [ ... ] )
```

And an example:

```
CREATE TABLE "D:\Data\customer.dbf" (id I AUTOINC NEXTVALUE 1 STEP 1, name C(40), payment F(5,2))
```

Taken from [here](http://dbf-software.com/create-table.html).